# Regex to exclude ranges from comma separated list of integers

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want to write a regex that matches a list of numeric values (non-range), given in a comma-separated list, ranges allowed. Empty is not allowed.

For ex:
List:  1,5-10,20,30,40,50-60

Desired output:

1,20,30,40

I am trying the regex: 
(\d+)(?!((\d+)-(\d+))) and some varioations on it.
The look ahead negation seems to negate just the first character and not the entire group.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does this have to be a single regex?

Comment: what is your programming language?

Comment: It's just some tool that just has regex support.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following regex for your problem :

```
(?<!-)([1-9][0-9]*)((?=,)|$)

(?<!-) - Negative lookbehind which checks `-` not preceding number
([1-9][0-9]*) - getting number
((?=,)|$)  - Or with Positive lookahead and end of input 
              - Positive lookahead checks `,` is follwed by number
              - $ checks end of input
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a *[negative look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)* and *[positive look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)* assertion

```
(?<!-|\d)\d+(?=,|$)
```

**details**

- `(?<!-|\d)` look-behind to check not preceding by a `-` or `digit`
- `\d+` match any instances of digits
- `(?=,|$)` look-ahead for a `,` or end-of-string

see **[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eOS1yy/2)**

Comment: For input `1,5-10,20,300,40,50-60,70` 70 would be discarded by your regex. So, good to include that condition too.

Comment: @AkashKC ah, my bad.. missed that. thanks for pointing out :-)